huggingface train only new tokens embedding
I want to add new tokens to a huggingface model and train only their embeddings. How can I do that?
There are some ways to train only part of a weight tensor (e.g. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-i-freeze-weights-in-element-wise/117988), however they seem to have access and edit the model class, which probably requires a lot of work for every specific LLM I will work on, and I'm intending to do this training to a lot of different models.
Another way is to train all the model and after every step reassign all the weights except of the embeddings of the new tokens, which sounds inefficient and can even be just incorrect for certain optimizers (as explained in the above link).

First use the tokenizer to add new tokens and then resize the token embedings of the model:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_name = "your-model-name"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

new_tokens = ["new_token1", "new_token2"]
tokenizer.add_tokens(new_tokens)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

Then, freeze all parameters except for the embeddings of the new tokens
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Get the new embedding indices
new_token_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(new_tokens)
new_embeddings = model.get_input_embeddings().weight.data[new_token_ids]

# Unfreeze the new token embeddings
for idx in new_token_ids:
    model.get_input_embeddings().weight.data[idx].requires_grad = True

Finally, implement the trainign loop, ensuring only the new embeddings are updated:
from torch.optim import AdamW
from torch.nn import functional as F

optimizer = AdamW(model.get_input_embeddings().parameters(), lr=1e-4)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in dataloader:
        inputs = batch["input_ids"]
        labels = batch["labels"]

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

This way you avoid the inefficiency of reassigning weights and you can straightforwardly apply it across different models.
